# SQL Server Always On + changing Isolation level of SPID

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, alwayson

Is there any reason why I cannot change the isolation level of a spid running against a primary database in an always on configuration?

Scenario: we are running CRM Dynamics upgrade tool. It was being blocked when trying to run the following command in SQL Server:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

On checking the error logs for the upgrade tool it says

> The operation cannot be performed on database "My_CRM_DB" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.

I'd like to understand why this is. I can't find anything online in technet that says I shouldn't be allowed to set a spid's isolation level to read committed when using AlwaysOn

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Have you actually tried running that statement in isolation and verified that this statement is definitely to blame? I suspect that the error may be arising from some other statement in your upgrade script.

Comment: Please move this question to dba.stackexchange.com where it belongs, it is not a programming questions.